# Does AWS CodeDeploy supports lambda and APIGateway

Tags: aws-code-deploy

Does AWS Code Deploy supports lambda and APIGateway?

I am looking for a solution to manage (deploy and transfer between aws accounts) my functions, methods and APi on Lambda and Gateway.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

No, CodeDeploy does not provide support for any of these yet. We have support for Lambda in our road map for this year.

Answer (score 1):

CodeDeploy support is now built in to the Serverless Application Model, which can hopefully do what you're after: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/automating-updates-to-serverless-apps.html

It can certainly deploy and update Lambda-backed API Gateways. Not sure what you mean by transferring between AWS accounts, but you can deploy the same SAM template in multiple places.